# What are the Java equivalents of C# 'is' and 'as' keywords?

Tags: c#, java, casting

Question says it all. Some quick code examples of usage would be nice.. thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`is` => `instanceof` ([JLS reference](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.20.2)), like this:

```
Object foo = "hello";
if (foo instanceof String) {
  // Yup, it's a string
}
```

There's no equivalent of C#'s `as` operator in Java.

Answer (score 2):

`is` (C#) -> `instanceof` (Java)

And you get no direct equivalent of `as`. You could try this one-liner though:

```
SomeParentType obj = 
    original instanceof Child ? (SomeParentType)original : null;
```

Comment: One thing: when you use operator "as" there is one cast, but in this case there are two casts.

Comment: @Sergey - there is a good chance that the JIT compiler will optimize the second typecast away.